# How do I use a .pkpass file in a Windows Phone application?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, zip, passbook

I need to get the data from an iOS Passbook file to use in my Windows Phone application. I'm able to get it downloaded but how do I get the data from it? It seems binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.pkpass` file is actually a *ZIP archive*. Inside the archive you'll find a `pass.json` file which contain all meta data for the pass.

Use the Windows Phone compatible ZIP library [Silverlight SharpZipLib](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/) to extract `pass.json` from the `.pkpass`.

```
string passDotJsonAsJson = null;
using(Stream pkpassAsStream = await client.GetPkpass())
{
    responseStream.Position = 0;
    using(ZipFile pkpass = new ZipFile(pkpassAsStream))
    {
        var passDotJson = pkpass.GetEntry("pass.json");

        using (var passDotJsonAsStream = pkpass.GetInputStream(passDotJson)) 
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(passDotJsonAsStream);
            passDotJsonAsJson = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And there you have it. `passDotJsonAsJson` does now contain the pass as a json string. You can now use [Json.NET](http://www.json.net/) to make it a .NET object.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?

Comment: thanks a lot for such an answer, I could not find suitable application for opening .pkpass, so I would write my own just to try xamarin)